# Could not grant roles permission in "Run SQL Command Line" powered by oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to create a role in an Oracle 11g database using the SQL Command Line, but I am receiving errors related to insufficient privileges. Specifically, I am trying to grant the "CREATE ANY ROLE" privilege to the user account, but I am receiving an "ORA-00911: invalid character" error.

Steps taken:

- Created a new database on Oracle 11g with a user account named "21F_9208".
- 
- Connected to the database using the SQL Command Line and verified that the user account can view tables in the database.
- 
- Attempted to create a new role using the following SQL command:
- 
- CREATE ROLE superadmin;
- 
- Received an error message indicating that the user did not have sufficient privileges to create a role.
- 
- Attempted to grant the "CREATE ANY ROLE" privilege to the user account using the following SQL command:
- 
- GRANT CREATE ANY ROLE TO 21F_9208;
- 
- Received an "ORA-00911: invalid character" error message.
- 

Potential solutions by CHAT GPT but I am beginner so that did not helped me out:

- Verify that the user account has the necessary permissions to create roles and grant privileges. This may involve checking the user's roles and privileges using the SQL Command Line or Oracle Enterprise Manager.
- Check the syntax of the SQL commands to ensure that they are properly formatted and do not contain any typos or errors.
- Contact Oracle support for assistance in resolving the issue, particularly if the user does not have the necessary permissions to perform the required tasks.

just want to give permissions to the my oracle 11g database 21F_9208 so that I can execute this statement to complete my assignment:
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON admin TO superadmin;

This is role which need to be given permission to do the following things on the admin table

Answer (score 2):

Only privileged users (such as `SYS`, unless you created your own) can create new users.

It means that `SYS` first has to

```
grant create role to "21F_9208";
```

(by the way, that's **poorly chosen username**; why did you set it that way? Now you have to qualify it using double quotes every time, as its name starts with a number. That is reason for error you got: "`ORA-00911: invalid character`").

That user (`"21F_9208"`) - apparently - owns table named `admin` because you want to grant DML privileges (select, insert, ...) on it to newly created role, `superadmin`.

---

Here's a walkthrough.

Creating new user:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL> select tablespace_name from dba_tablespaces;

TABLESPACE_NAME
------------------------------
SYSTEM
SYSAUX
UNDOTBS1
TEMP
USERS

SQL> create user "21F_9208" identified by demo
  2  default tablespace users
  3  quota unlimited on users
  4  temporary tablespace temp;

User created.
```

Granting basic privileges (just to make this example work):

```
SQL> grant create session, create table, create role to "21F_9208";

Grant succeeded.
```

Connect as newly create user:

```
SQL> connect "21F_9208"/demo@pdb1
Connected.
```

Create table:

```
SQL> create table admin (id number);

Table created.
```

Create role:

```
SQL> create role superadmin;

Role created.
```

Grant privileges to role:

```
SQL> grant select, insert, update, delete on admin to superadmin;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>
```